# Collapse row on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found one very good example of Collapsible Content on Internet but it's unfinished.

```
<div class="container faq_wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <p>
                &nbsp;</p>
            <div class="faq-all-actions">
                <a class="faq-expand" onclick="jQuery('.answer-wrapper').css('display','block');">Expand All</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="faq-collapse" onclick="jQuery('.answer-wrapper').css('display','none');">Collapse All</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <div class="question-wrapper">
                <div class="arrow">
                    &nbsp;</div>
                <div class="big-q">
                    Q</div>
                <div class="question">
                    <h6>Can I try the software before I buy it?</div></h6>
                <div class="answer-wrapper">
                    <div class="big-a">
                        A</div>
                    <div class="answer">
                        Yes! Simply <a href="/trial">download a free trial</a> and you&#39;ll have instant access to all features for 30 days, absolutely free. We don&#39;t require your credit card details or any commitment.</div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I can expand or hide the answer from the example when I click on the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a click event to the row and hide/show the child using `.find()`

```
<style>
    .answer-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

$(document)
    .on('click','.row',function(){ 
        $(this).find('.answer-wrapper').slideToggle();
    })
;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bz5au97/

If you bind the event to the document, you won't have to worry about the DOM changing due to ajax calls or dynamic content.

Comment: The code is not working properly. When I expand it it's auto hidden again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it even without JS using only CSS. Just see this example:

```css
.collapsible > .item {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
.collapsible > .item > .row {
  display: block;
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 5px;
}
.collapsible > .item > .content {
  display: none;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
.collapsible > .item > input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.collapsible > .item > input[type=checkbox]:checked + .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible">
  <label class="item">
    <span class="row">Row 1</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="content">Content 1</span>
  </label>
  <label class="item">
    <span class="row">Row 2</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="content">Content 2</span>
  </label>
  <label class="item">
    <span class="row">Row 3</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="content">Content 3</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this, toggle and find

```
$('.row').click(function(){
  $(this).find('.answer-wrapper').toggle();
})
```

don't forget use on if you are adding your rows dynamically:

```
$('.row').on('click',function(){
  $(this).find('.answer-wrapper').toggle();
})
```

Comment: assigning the event to `$('.row') directly can result in multiple events being fired. You should bind to a node higher in the DOM that doesn't change.

Comment: That's true. you can use: $('.container').on('click','.row', function(){
//other statement
})